# Creating a Discord bot to play an Icecast server

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to create a Discord bot that plays an Icecast stream in the room the user is currently in. I'm not sure why this isn't working. I am using Discord.py

**Python**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
try:
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soupAvailable = True
except:
    soupAvailable = False
import urllib.request as urllib2
import ffmpy
import asyncio

if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
discord.opus.load_opus('/usr/local/lib/libopus.so')

...

@_radio.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(self, ctx):

    client = discord.Client()
    channel = discord.VoiceState(voice_channel)
    voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    player = voice.create_ffmpeg_player('http://srv.flare-radio.com:8000/stream')
    player.start()
```

Comment: What isn't working? Could you provide a bit more information?

Comment: Doesn't `create_ffmpeg_player` take a filename as first argument?

Comment: If I'm reading over the documentation correctly one needs to pass pipe=True when they call create_ffmpeg_player and file needs to be a datagram pipe to content being streamed via a call to urllib.request.get

Comment: @Karatawi dug further into the code, https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/voice_client.py#L420 just joins fffmpeg a few options and passes the `-i input_url` (yes input_url is correct and from the ffmpeg documentation) so in theory it _should_ work

Comment: @luke-hallett  is there anyway you could provide a pastebin with debugging info?